# Can windows credentials be stored for 'All Users'?

Tags: credentials

I am looking for a way to store windows credentials for 'All Users' as opposed to individually-named Users in Win7. Issue - we have a company server that is being accessed by multiple users. Each user logs on to the server with their unique user credentials. While working on the server, each user has need to access paid-for-services via a state (as in ND) web site. When they click on the web site link for these services, they are presented with a Windows Security challenge. All unique users enter a common set of credentials (same username & password) for access to the state server. The user only has to enter the state credentials once and they are good the rest of the day even as they log off and log back on to our company server. The kicker is that all individual user profiles are auto-deleted every night for business reasons. The users are wondering if there was some way the state credentials can be stored so that no matter what user logs on to the company server, the state credentials will always be available when they try to access the state's paid-for-services, without having to type them in every day.

Comment: so is this state server meant to accessed by a single common set of credentials?

Comment: Yes, by users within our company. Users of the state server from other companies have their own username/password, but we're obviously not concerned with them. One username/password used by all users within our company.

Comment: I wonder the same thing as Tony.  What he means is, does the state ALLOW you to actually use a single username/pwd for all your employees?  Sounds like a way to not have to pay for individual accounts, but we could be completely wrong.

Comment: Yes, one un/pw per company for access to information on state system re: oil and gas exploration.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a browser caching question? Perhaps I misunderstood the scenario and your needs, but would a plugin like "Last Pass" work for you? Typically in these scenarios you can use Google Chrome or alternative browser plugins to remember or cache credentials for common websites and have them auto fill the info for you. Just a thought. The reason I suggest the browser plugin is because you're authenticating against the state server, and not so much against any account in your domain/workgroup. These credentials should be eligible to be stored in a browser cache if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been completely clear. The user profiles on the company server are deleted every night for business reasons and re-established as brand new profiles (for the day) the next time each user logs in. Consequently, any user+browser-related info is gone when the user logs back on tomorrow.

Re: LastPass - looking at it right now but maybe you know the answer to this question - can LastPass be set up to be active under the same account no matter what user is logged onto the machine? Would not want to have to log into the LP account each time as that what we are trying to avoid.